# Identifying the checkbox which is being checked in the rows of DataView in Wicket

Tags: java, checkbox, wicket

I populated a checkbox for every row item in DataView. I need to be able to identify the checkbox in which rows are being checked in order to retrieve the id of those rows and store them into a list. Therefore, I can use those row´s ids to modify the identical rows in the database table. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach would be:

- Reflect the status of the checkbox in your model.
- Iterate over your List or whatever is holding your models
- Read the model-value for your checkbox
- react accordingly

But without any code it's hard to give a more detailed answer

Comment: a great suggestion. I also recommend this link for anyone who's looking for a solution for the similar problem http://markmail.org/message/pck267qo5ejfi3jj#query:+page:1+mid:pck267qo5ejfi3jj+state:results